# powershell restart websphere on windows box

Tags: powershell, websphere

Newbee to powershell and I don't know websphere application server at all

I need to write a powershell script that does the following: 
"It is currently done manually"
Runing on windows server 2012 box

1)
     **Turning off the application**
     Using the services console
       1.   On **server 2**– stop node2 
            a.  Wait for the stop progress bar to disappear before proceeding
                with the next step
       2.   On **Server 1**– stop node3 
            a.  Wait for the stop progress bar to disappear before proceeding
                with the next step
       3.   On **server 1**– stop node2 
            a.  Wait for the stop progress bar to disappear before proceeding
                with the next step
       4.   On **Server 2**– stop node1 
            a.  Wait for the stop progress bar to disappear before proceeding
                with the next step
       5.   On **Server 1**– stop node1 
            a.  Wait for the stop progress bar to disappear before proceeding
                with the next step
       6.   On **Server 2**– stop cell manager 
            a.  Wait for the stop progress bar to disappear before proceeding
                with the next step
       7.   On Server 1– stop cell manager 
            a.  Wait for the stop progress bar to disappear before proceeding
                with the next step
       8.   Kill any remaining websphere java.exe still showing in task manager
            Details (Right Click, End Process Tree)

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programmer Q&A site, not a "code on demand" site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on powershell, but a shell-agnostic way to shut down WAS is to execute the stopServer.bat script in each profile's bin dir, with the name of the server to stop as the parameter. So a script to shut down several nodes across several systems would connect to each one, and execute stopServer.bat for each server (this includes the nodeagent for each node, and the dmgr.) The command won't return until the server has stopped.

Here's the doc for stopServer: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_stopserver.html

For a force kill, I usually like wmic:
`wmic process where "name like '%java%' and commandline like '%WAS90%'" delete`

Any powershell tutorial should be able to show you how to wire those statements up into a script.